# If all SQL queries should be prepared to prevent SQL injections, why does the syntax allow non-prepared queries?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-injection

Since all SQL queries should be prepared to prevent SQL injections, why are we allowed to write and execute non-prepared queries? Doesn't this seem counterintuitive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cases where the query is a fixed string and does not need any program variables, it's safe to use `query()` to run it.

Here's the example from https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php:

```
<?php
$sql = 'SELECT name, color, calories FROM fruit ORDER BY name';
foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
    print $row['name'] . "\t";
    print $row['color'] . "\t";
    print $row['calories'] . "\n";
}
```

The query has no PHP variables in it. The `query()` is sufficient, and accomplishes the same as `prepare()` and `execute()`.

If you need to substitute PHP variables for values in SQL expressions, then you would use parameters:

```
$sql = 'SELECT name, colour, calories FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour';
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute(array('calories' => 150, 'colour' => 'red'));
```

You might find that this is more common in your application than running a fixed query.

Comment: "If you need to substitute PHP variables for values in SQL expressions, then you would use parameters:" I'd argue you don't strictly /need/ to do that if you're generating the values assigned to those variables internally.  I.e. if it's an integer value you're calculating.  Of course using `prepare` sometimes and string concatenation other times is messy, so there's an argument you might as well always use `prepare` unless you have a good reason not to.

Comment: I think it's better to use query parameters consistently, so you don't have to explain to junior developers how to tell the difference when to use them and when you "don't have to." Just use query parameters as the default whenever you combine a PHP variable with an SQL query. If that's the standard, then you don't have to think about it every time.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you require using prepared statements, there's no way to prevent the prepared statement from being created from variable substitution. E.g.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM someTable WHERE id = $id";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
```

Comment: Well actually there was an RFC to employ a "tainted" attribute for the data. But it didn't end well.

Answer (score 1):

Bound parameters and [query preparation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html) are two different things. You can do one or the other or both.

You need to bind parameters to prevent SQL injection. However, there are things that cannot be passed as parameters (e.g. ORDER BY list), in which case you can concatenate the desired SQL syntax directly into the SQL string. This is called "dynamic SQL" and should generally use only whitelisted strings to prevent SQL injection.

So to answer (what I think was) you question: dynamic SQL is allowed because there are cases not covered by the bound parameters.

Comment: FWIW, you cannot use bound parameters without doing `prepare()`.

Comment: @BillKarwin I think that depends on the client library. For example, ADO.NET will allow you to bind parameters without calling `DbCommand.Prepare`, or at least that's how it works for Oracle and MS SQL Server. Same for ODBC. It was a long time since I last tried it with MySQL though, so correct me if I'm wrong on that...

Comment: It must have wrapped the prepare and execute in a convenience function that does both calls. But the point of bound parameters is to separate the dynamic content from the SQL parsing steps. If the ADO.NET is just interpolating variables into the SQL string (with some escaping to make it "safe"), and then calling `query()` on the resulting string, then it's not doing bound parameters.

Comment: SQL Server differentiates between "direct" execution (where the entire SQL text is passed to the server) and "prepared" execution (where just the handle of the previously prepared SQL statement is passed). It is entirely possible to include bound parameters with the "direct" call. No string interpolation takes place - these are "real" bound parameters. I think the confusion may arise because the term "preparation" is often understood as simply "parsing and planning", while leaving out the "return the statement handle to the client" part.